# How can I pass checkout rules to TeamCity for SVN?

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, teamcity

I currently have a script that extracts .sql files from SVN and creates a build package that can then be deployed on to a database. The script reads in a text file in which I specify the .sql files it needs to fetch from SVN and where they reside in SVN. TeamCity currently executes this script for me without any issues.

However, I would like TeamCity to manage the SVN interaction and extract the required .sql scripts to form the build package. TeamCity will still run the same (modified) script to form the build package structure - but the script will have been edited so it does not connect to SVN anymore.

I have read up about checkout rules in TeamCity but I am not sure if this is what I need.

Note, that the .sql files that form the build package live in the same VCS root, but under many different folders under the root and that I may only need to obtain one .sql file from a VCS folder that may contain several .sql files.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any reason, why you are unsure about TeamCity checkout rules?